# Podio .Net CreateItem app-reference

Tags: .net, api, podio

I'm trying to create a new item in Podio using .Net for an app that uses an app field that is referenced from another app ("sending-location").
I keep getting an **error**

```
error 400, field.app.invalid, the referenced item is not valid.
```

I'm trying to hard code the id value for testing purposes but to no avail have I managed to get this to work.
if I remove the app field I'm able to create the item, but I need that field.

My code is provided below.

```
Item myNewItem = new Item();            

// App Field with external_id 'sending-location' 
var clientField = myNewItem.Field<AppItemField>("sending-location");                                   
clientField.ItemId = 15;            

// Text Field with external_id 'status' 
var statusField = myNewItem.Field<CategoryItemField>("status");
statusField.OptionId = 1;

//Text Field with external_id 'priority' 
var priorityField = myNewItem.Field<CategoryItemField>("priority");
if(((DropDownList)fvSupportRequest.FindControl("ddlPriority")).SelectedValue == "Standard")            
    priorityField.OptionId = 1;
else
    priorityField.OptionId = 2;

// Text Field with external_id 'receiving-referring-location' 
var detailsField = myNewItem.Field<TextItemField>("receiving-referring-location");
detailsField.Value = ((TextBox)fvSupportRequest.FindControl("txtLocId")).Text + "<br />" 
                   + ((TextBox)fvSupportRequest.FindControl("txtSuppDetails")).Text;          

int itemId = podio.ItemService.AddNewItem(podio_eReports_AppId, myNewItem);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `app_item_id` and not the `item_id`. Go to your item, click the "Actions" dropdown at the top and pick the "Developer" option. There you can see the `item_id` -- it will be a much larger number